# Terraform multi-level maps

Tags: dictionary, terraform, multi-level

I'm getting errors on "terraform plan" when trying to use a multi-level map (3+ levels) and can't seem to put my finger on the exact problem. The error: "The given value is not valid for variable "secgroups": element "bastion": attribute "direction" is required." Is my variables.tf correct as mapped to secgroups.auto.tf? ports_min and ports_max will be an all-inclusive list of ports to open for the security group name.

## Versions:

```
Terraform v0.13.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local v1.4.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/null v2.1.2
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/tls v2.2.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/terraform-providers/openstack v1.26.0
```

## variables.tf

```
variable "secgroups" {
  type = map(object({
  direction = (map(object({
    protocols = (map(object({
      name              = string
      description       = string
      ports_min         = list(number)
      ports_max         = list(number)
      remote_ip_prefix  = list(string)
      remote_group_id   = list(string)
      security_group_id = list(string)
    })))
  })))
 }))
}
```

## secgroups.auto.tfvars  (just a snippet)

```
  ssh_from_bastion = {
    ingress = {
      tcp = {
        ports_min         = [22]
        ports_max         = [22]
        remote_group_id   = ["openstack_networking_secgroup_v2.bastion.id"]
        security_group_id = ["openstack_networking_secgroup_v2.bastion.id"]
      },
      udp = {
        ports_min         = [0]
        ports_max         = [0]
        remote_group_id   = ["openstack_networking_secgroup_v2.bastion.id"]
        security_group_id = ["openstack_networking_secgroup_v2.bastion.id"]
      }
    },
    egress = {
      tcp = {
        ports_min         = [0]
        ports_max         = [0]
        remote_ip_prefix  = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
        security_group_id = ["openstack_networking_secgroup_v2.bastion.id"]
      },
      udp = {
        ports_min         = [0]
        ports_max         = [0]
        remote_ip_prefix  = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
        security_group_id = ["openstack_networking_secgroup_v2.bastion.id"]
      }
    }
  },
```

## Main.tf

```
 locals {
   security_groups = flatten({
   for secgroup_name,direction in var.secgroups : {
     name        = each.secgroup_name
     description = "Security group for ${each.secgroup_name}"
       for protocol,config in each.direction : {
         direction = each.direction
         protocol  = each.protocol
           for config_value in config : {
             ports_min         = each.config_value.ports_min
             ports_max         = each.config_value.ports_max
             remote_ip_prefix  = each.config_value.remote_ip_prefix
             security_group_id = each.config_value.security_group_id
           }
         }
       }
   })
 }
```

Comment: When you specify an `object` type, you must provide the argument as written by the name you specified. The key cannot be any string. It seems like what you really want here is `map(map(map(object)))`, but this could also be refactored quite easily into a flattened `map(object)`.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I have flatten in my main.tf file and I posted it above. Is it there I need to change or the variables.tf definition? I'm fairly new to this, so please forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with your definitions.

Assuming that your full `secgroups.auto.tfvars` is:

```
secgroups = {
 ssh_from_bastion = {
    ingress = {
      tcp = {
        ports_min         = [22]
        ports_max         = [22]
        remote_group_id   = ["openstack_networking_secgroup_v2.bastion.id"]
        security_group_id = ["openstack_networking_secgroup_v2.bastion.id"]
      },
      udp = {
        ports_min         = [0]
        ports_max         = [0]
        remote_group_id   = ["openstack_networking_secgroup_v2.bastion.id"]
        security_group_id = ["openstack_networking_secgroup_v2.bastion.id"]
      }
    },
    egress = {
      tcp = {
        ports_min         = [0]
        ports_max         = [0]
        remote_ip_prefix  = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
        security_group_id = ["openstack_networking_secgroup_v2.bastion.id"]
      },
      udp = {
        ports_min         = [0]
        ports_max         = [0]
        remote_ip_prefix  = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
        security_group_id = ["openstack_networking_secgroup_v2.bastion.id"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The corresponding definition should be:

```
variable "secgroups" {
  type = map(map(map(object({
        ports_min         = list(number)
        ports_max         = list(number)
        security_group_id = list(string)
      }))))
}
```

But the above inner object will drop all extra attributes, such as `remote_ip_prefix` because your objects are inconsistent. However, since `ingress`, `egress`, `tcp` and `udp` seem to be consistent, you could probably use the following:

```
variable "secgroups" {
  type = map(object({
            ingress = object({tcp = map(any), udp = map(any)})
            egress =  object({tcp = map(any), udp = map(any)})
        }))
}
```

As the last resource, if nothing is consistent, then you can use:

```
variable "secgroups" {
  type = map(map(map(map(any))))
}
```

#### Update: test output

```
output "test" {
  value = var.secgroups.ssh_from_bastion.ingress.tcp.ports_min
}
```

Comment: Would I then refer to the individual value in the module as: var.secgroups.ssh_from_bastion.ingress.tcp.ports_min, etc, the get that specific value?