# Terraform Create a policy using values from a multi-level map

Tags: terraform

Terraform v1.0.11

I want to use a list to construct a policy that iterates between different levels.

I will have one policy per app (ie app1), containing statements in order from each application within that app (ie app1-123, app1-456).

for example:

Name: Policy for app1 users
Statements:
define group app1-123 as id.group.abcdefg
define group app1-456 as id.group.hijklm
allow group app1-123 to manage resources
allow group app1-456 to manage resources

I have a list containing multiple levels in app.tfvars (snippet):

```
apps = {
  "app1" = {
    "app1-123" = {
      app_name = "123"
      app_prefix = "app1"
      group_id = "id.group.abcdefg..."
    },
    "app-456" = {
      app_prefix = "app1"
      app_name = "456"
      group_id = "id.group.hijklm"
    }
  },
  "app2" = {
    "app2-123" = {
      app_prefix = "app2"
      app_name = "123"
      group_id = "id.group.nopqrs"
    },
    "app2-456" = {
      app_prefix = "app2"
      app_name = "456"
      group_id = "id.group.tuvwx"
    },
    "app2-789" = {
      app_prefix = "app2"
      app_name = "789"
      group_id = "id.group.yzabc"
    }
  }
}
```

I have the following in my variables.tf:

```
variable "apps" {
  type = map(map(object({
    app_name   = string
    app_prefix = string
    group_id   = string
  }))
}
```

Policy resource:

```
resource "identity_policy" "app_explicit" {
  for_each = var.apps

  compartment_id = var.tenancy_id
  description = "Policy for ${each.key} App"
  name = "${each.key}AppUsers"
  statements = [
    "define group ${each.value["app_prefix"]}${each.value["app_name"]} as ${each.value["group_id"]}",
    "admit group ${each.value["app_prefix"]}${each.value["app_name"]} "
  ]
}
```

The error I encounter:

```
│     │ each.value is map of object with 3 elements
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

I've tried a few possible methods from the following pages:

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/flatten#flattening-nested-structures-for-for_each

[Terraform multi-level maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63604408/terraform-multi-level-maps)